# Change navbar and menu position in magento 2

Tags: magento2

hi my current behavior of theme is 
[image]

And I want to do this like this
[image]

I tried to change it in admin area but could not find any option to preposition it. Its my first ever experience so dont know much about it .

**EDIT**

My default.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this file `/app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`, you must put below code and your navigation is moving after logo.

In below code, you have a block element which moved in the same line with logo.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

You need clear cache.

Comment: thank you for reply . I have updated my default.xml can you exactly tell where to replace please ?

Comment: you need clear cache magento

Comment: I did , I just asking I should replace full file with your code just ? mean Just your code in default.xml ?

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer, you have to put this code `<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />` up in the body, after that you can have any other codes.

Comment: yes things got change but logo is on upside of that strip not exactly align.

Comment: because you have 'search' in the same line, please check your HTML code, or for test please delete 'search' element with InspectElement.

Comment: where html code of this page I will find ? yes I got what you saying . I am accepting answer just tell me where to modify colors etc and html ?

Comment: you can change styles in `magento/app/design/frontend/VendorName/Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less`, but you need compile less with grunt or with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=VendorName/Theme`, this command you must run in project root.

Comment: for HTML, it depends on what you need to modify

Comment: I need to modify home page all things like navbar , product places footer all things .

Comment: You find that in `/vendor/magento`, in this folder you have Magento core modules, and you find in every modules `view/fronted/` folder where are layouts, templates, and styles. You can find by element class.